# How can I ignore files when deploying a Flask app to Azure App Service?

Tags: python, azure-appservice

I am running a Flask application on Azure App Service. I use the Azure CLI for deploying the app. I have the following questions (and I could not find the answers in the AZ docs):

1. When creating the zip file for deploying to the server, does the azure setup ignore files in line with `.gitignore` file.
2. Is there a way to ignore a file for git (by putting it in `.gitignore`) and keep it out of source control, but have the file be part of the azure zip file?
3. Is there a way to have azure ignore files based on a different file, instead of `.gitignore`? For example, Google Cloud App Engine has a `.gcloudignore` file.
4. Is there a way to view the zip file that azure creates for deployment, without manually creating the zip file for deployment.